# Receiving a response from Express.js sendFile() is a corrupted PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf

The flow I'm working on requires that sending a POST request from the client to the server and the server generates a PDF file and return it back to be downloaded. the server generates the PDF correctly but when I receive it at the client-side it's corrupted (white empty pages).

How can I receive it correctly? or is the problem is on the server side?

server

```
    async createDraft(req, res) {
        try {
            Log.debug("Server.createDraft", "Trying to create draft file");

            const authorized = await this.isAuthorized(req);

            if(!authorized)
                return res.status(301).redirect(this.cognito.getFederatedLoginURL());

            const questionnaire = await this.db.getQuestionnaire(req.params.id);
            const fileName      = getDraftFileName(questionnaire);

            await create(req.body, fileName, questionnaire.id);
            Log.debug("Server.createDraft", "Successfully created draft");

            const file = path.join(__dirname, `../static/${fileName}`);

            if(fs.existsSync(file))
                return res.status(200).sendFile(file);


            res.status(500);
            console.log("File not found");
            return res.send("File not found");
        } catch(e) {
            Log.info("Server.createDraft", `Error while answering POST /draft - ${e.message}...`);
            return badRequest(res, e.message);
        }
    }




const create = async (data, fileName, id) => {
    const output   = path.join(__dirname, "../../static/");
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../draft/");
    const tmp      = path.join(__dirname, "../../tmp/");
    const content  = `${tmp}draft-${id}.html`;
    const cover    = `${tmp}cover-${id}.html`;

    await Q.all([
        Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile, content, data.content),
        Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile, cover, data.cover)
    ]);
    await Q.all([
        Q.nfcall(exec, `wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access --encoding 'UTF-8' toc --xsl-style-sheet ${filePath}toc.xsl --header-html ${filePath}header.html --header-spacing 10 --footer-html ${filePath}footer.html --footer-spacing 10 ${content} --header-html ${filePath}header.html --header-spacing 10 --footer-html ${filePath}footer.html --footer-spacing 10 ${output}content-${fileName}`),
        Q.nfcall(exec, `wkhtmltopdf --enable-local-file-access --encoding 'UTF-8' -T 0 -B 0 cover ${cover} ${output}cover-${fileName}`)
    ]);
    await Q.nfcall(exec, `pdftk ${output}cover-${fileName} ${output}content-${fileName} cat output ${output}${fileName}`);


    await Q.all([
        Q.nfcall(fs.unlink, `${tmp}draft-${id}.html`),
        Q.nfcall(fs.unlink, `${tmp}cover-${id}.html`),
        Q.nfcall(fs.unlink, `${output}content-${fileName}`),
        Q.nfcall(fs.unlink, `${output}cover-${fileName}`)
    ]);
};
```

client

```
// eslint-disable-next-line max-statements
export const exportDraft = async (tree, data) => {
    try {
        tree.set("loading", true);
        tree.commit();

        document.getElementById("cover-title").innerHTML = data.draft.secoDraft;

        const path = window.location.pathname.split("/");
        const id   = parseInt(path[ path.length - 1 ], 10);

        const res = await axios({
            url:          `${window.location.origin}/draft/${id}`,
            method:       "POST",
            responseType: "blob",
            data:         {
                cover: `<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/draft/wysiwyg.css" />
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/draft/test.css" />
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            ${document.getElementById("cover").innerHTML}
                        </body>
                    </html>`,
                content: `<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/draft/wysiwyg.css" />
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/draft/test.css" />
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            ${document.getElementById("draft").innerHTML}
                        </body>
                    </html>
                `
            },
            json: true
        });

        console.log(res);
        tree.set("loading", false);
        const file = new Blob([res], { type: "application/pdf" });

        return saveAs(file, "PDF-Draft.pdf");
    } catch(e) {
        tree.set("loading", false);
        return add(tree, "error", e.message);
    }
};
```

Comment: This seems like you need to do some basic debugging.  Check the file that the client uploaded to the server.  Is that file exactly as it should be?  Generate the PDF from that file on the server.  Check that file on the server - is the PDF working there?  If either of those was incorrect, then you know which step to debug further.  If those were both correct, then the problem must be in the final transfer to the client and you can focus your debugging there.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, the file is generated at the server correctly, the problem happens when I receive the file at the client-side.

Comment: Is the client a browser?  What client-side library is `request()` from?  What does `saveAs()` do?  Does `create()` on the server return a promise that resolves when the file creation is done?

Comment: the server waits till the file is done then sends it back. 

the client is a browser

and I use

import request from "request-promise";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

Comment: I asked about the `create()` function (which you don't show us) because if the server wasn't properly waiting until the file was completely done, and started to send it back before then, that would be an easy way to end up sending back a corrupted file.  I don't know about your code, but lots and lots of people here slap an `await` in front of something that doesn't return a promise and expect it to do miracles.  That's why I'm pursing that path as it seems the most likely source of corruption.

Comment: Where is documentation for `request-promise` that supports browser-side use with Blobs?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry I'm really new in the full-stack field so I'm still learning, Your comment about request-promise is right so I changed it to Axios but the same behavior happens. Also I updated the question with create() code

Comment: Can you show the axios client code you're now using?  The `create()` code would benefit from use the `fs.promises` interface so you don't have to use `Q.nfcall()`, but I don't see anything obviously wrong with it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated the question with the recent code

Comment: @jfriend00 It's working after changing to axios and fixing the Blob arguments

        const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Using res.data to extract the pdf data solved the problem

```
        const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
```